# XML processing in C++

Tags: c++, xml

All,

we currently use TinyXML for authoring XML files and expat for parsing them. Our XML files are ultra simple, no DTD, etc...Does anyone have any experience using TinyXML for parsing XML files? I hate to use 2 different packages for XML processing. Thoughts?

Comment: What's the question? Just thoughts on TinyXML? It does what it says: parse XML.

Comment: any experiences using TinyXML for parsing XML. Any shortcomings, ease of use, stability, etc...

Comment: My experience with it was good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with TinyXML was remarkably good, too. I expected it to have trouble when we started using more complex XML, but it turns out that TinyXML is so simple that it's hard to mess it up too badly.

I think you can guess the things we had trouble with (missing tags, malformed tags, etc.), but these would be problems with any parser.

I would suggest looking at TinyXML++. http://code.google.com/p/ticpp/